# Can you have multiple instances of a WTForm?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am implementing a commenting system (using Python/Flask/WTForms) on an internal application and it allows for Comments, and a single level of subcomments under each.

The Comments work fine with a simple WTForm class like:

class CommentForm(Form):
    comment = TextAreaField('Comment', validators=[DataRequired()])

That is then called into the Jinja2 template.

The question is how to go about implementing 'sub' comments. It's a basic many-to-one foreign key relationship between Subcomment and parent Comment. The challenge is that there can be multiple Comments on a given screen, but there where only be one comment form. However, there are Subcomments associated with each Comment, therefor the Subcomment form will need to be rendered multiple times on the screen (under each comment) and I anticipate conflicts both in rendering and form submission (using WTForms here).

The model is very similar to Stackoverflow where there is a Question > Many Comments associated with Question and > Many SubComments associated with each Comment.

Would it be easier to simply not use WTForms for the Subcomments and expose a simple REST API and spin a little AJAX to submit the Subcomment to the REST endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's much simpler to only create a form when you need to than to ship N+1 forms (where N is the number of comments) to the client - however, if you are looking at taking a progressive-enhancement approach then that's what you need to do.

In that case, you simply are going to be transforming your data into a form, and handling the response on the server side:

```
class CommentForm(Form):
    parent_id = IntegerField(widget=HiddenWidget)
    comment = TextAreaField("Comment", validators=[InputRequired()])

# Then, in your view handler
comments = get_comment_list()
comments = [CommentForm(comment.id, comment.text) for comment in comments]
return render_template(article=article, comments=comments)

# And in your "comment" endpoint you simply handle the comment
comment = CommentForm(request.post)

# This shouldn't be necessary, but it's just an example of figuring out
# what's going on from the data provided
if comment.parent_id.data:
    # Insert into comment chain
else:
    # It is a rootless comment
```